# How should I prove that the collection of open intervals formed below are pairwise disjoint?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $U$ be any non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $x \in U$.

Let $a(x)=\inf \{z \mid (z, x)\subseteq U\}, b(x)=\sup\{z\mid (x, z)\subseteq U \}$, and let $I(x)=(a(x), b(x))$. We're allowing $a(x)=-\infty$ and $b(x)=+\infty$.

How do I show that $a(x), b(x) \notin U$ and that the intervals $I(x)$ are pairwise disjoint?

For the first question, I think we can reason as follows that if $a(x)\in U$, then because $U$ is open, we can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $(a(x)-\epsilon, a(x)+\epsilon) \subseteq U$. We would then have that $(a(x)-\epsilon, x) \subseteq U$, contradicting the definition of $a(x)$.

For the second question, I'm assuming that there exists some $z \in I(x) \cap I(y)$ and trying to show that $I(x)=I(y)$. However, there seems to be a lot of cases to consider here and the inequalities are tripping me. Is there an easy argument I can use here that works and isn't too hard to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a typo there. The third line should read $a(x),b(x)\not\in U$. And your reasoning for that point is correct.

Second point: I guess you mean to say *the set of all $I(x)$ is pw. disjoint*. For this consider: For $a(x) < a' < b' < b(x)$ we have $(a',b')\subset U$. This then does imply that also $I(x) = (a(x), b(x))\subset U$. With the previous information this uniquely characterizes $I(x)$ as the largest interval in $U$ containing $x$. Quite obviously this property does not actually depend on which point $x\in I(x)$ you have chosen (all points in $I(x)$ lead to the same interval (also very easy to proof).

Thus if $z \in I(x)\cap I(y)$ we know $I(x) = I(z) = I(y)$.

Comment: Fixed the typo, and thank you for your answer. :)